# vim script for smart text replacement using variable/regexp

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim editing. I would like to create a script or an `:ab` command to smart replace using variables.

I thought to do it with an `:ab` command in my `vimrc` but i'm not sure how or if I can do it for variable.

For example, when im writing:

```
:<ab or something else> kuku v1 v2
```

where:

- `kuku` is a shortcut,
- `v1` is a first variable,
- `v2` is a second variable.

And i would like the replacement to write for me:

```
for (i=v1, i<=v2; i++){

}
```

Any idea how I implement it? The `for` loop was an example for a text replacement but I will need it for few variations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really put logic in abbreviations so you can forget about `:ab`.

The only built-in thing that can take arguments like what you describe is a custom command, as described under `:help user-commands`, possibly backed by a custom function, as described under `:help user-functions`.

Here is a crude approximation:

```
function! ForSnippet(init, max)
    put='for (i=' . a:init . ', i<=' . a:max . '; i++){'
    put='}'
    normal O
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ Kuku call ForSnippet(<f-args>)
```

That you would use like this:

```
:Kuku foo bar
```

Note that this is already quite involved for a crude solution and will require you to:

- make a lot of refinement before you get something usable,
- write and maintain lots of those things in the future.

Therefore, I would recommend you to *not* copy/paste the code above in your config and instead explore snippet expansion plugins like [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), which don't work exactly like you want but let you save quite a lot of typing.